# My app is crashing with 'Could not cast value of type x to 'UITableViewdelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

Error

> 2017-09-08 19:32:51.886 Metropolitan League 1.5.1[1602:24950] Unknown class parksTable in Interface Builder file.
>       Could not cast value of type 'Metropolitan_League_1_5_1.ParkViewController' (0x10189f950) to 'UITableViewDelegate' (0x103d7b870).
>   (lldb)

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ParkViewController: UIViewController {
     var parkNames = ["Sunnyside", "South Oak", "Tower", "Arno", "Arbor", "Holmes", "Brookside", "Brookside Tennis Courts", "Loose", "Gilham", "Brush Creek", "Westwood"]

    @IBOutlet weak var parksTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.parksTable.delegate = self as! UITableViewDelegate
        self.parksTable.dataSource = self as! UITableViewDataSource
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return parkNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        print(indexPath.row)

        cell.textLabel?.text = parkNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Also, in `viewDidLoad`, I'm getting the warning:

> 'Treating a forced downcast to "UITableViewDatasource" as optional will never produce nill'

What does this mean? The only reason I have the 'as! UITableViewDataSource' is because Xcode told me to.

Comment: `as!` is almost always a bad idea, especially if the compiler tells you to add it.  When you see that suggestion, you should try to understand the reason behind the error. In this case, it's because your view controller doesn't conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`, like it must to be assigned to those properties.

Comment: And the first message there is a misconfiguration in your xib/storyboard. You set the class of the table to `tableView`; you need to set a referencing outlet to the property instead.

Comment: Earlier someone told me the errors I was getting was because it DOES conform and that my code was redundant.

Comment: Also, do my xib and storyboard view controller need the same class name? the storyboard is named appropriately but the xib won't let me name a class..

Comment: A `UITableViewController` already conforms to the delegate and data source protocols, but you have a `UIViewController`, which does not.

Comment: Are you saying you have both a xib and a storyboard for the same class? That's... technically possible but almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: On top of everything else that is wrong with your code, your implementation of `cellForRowAt` is not creating a cell properly. Look at the countless table view samples and see how to properly dequeue a reusable cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this line:

```
class ParkViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {
```

Also, you are creating tableview programmatically which means you don't need IBOutlet as well. Otherwise you don't need to set delegate and data source in `viewDidLoad`.

So fix these few issues in your code and it should work.

```
class ParkViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource{
    var parkNames = ["Sunnyside", "South Oak", "Tower", "Arno", "Arbor", "Holmes", "Brookside", "Brookside Tennis Courts", "Loose", "Gilham", "Brush Creek", "Westwood"]

    var parksTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.parksTable.delegate = self as! UITableViewDelegate
        self.parksTable.dataSource = self as! UITableViewDataSource
    }
```

Comment: You do not need either `as! UITableViewXXX`.

Comment: And why do you state that the OP is creating the table view programmatically? There is no code shown in the question that creates the table view through code.

Comment: It finally worked!! Thank you.  See ya next error haha

Comment: also, I just deleted the ! from both but kept the as.

Comment: @Alexander Do not use `as` at all. Simply do `parksTable.delegate = self`. There is no need for the cast.

Comment: I did it like that but there were errors but it looks like it's running smoothly now.